# Exercise 3.2.17 in Durrett's book

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is an exercise in text R. Durrett, Probability: Theory and Examples, in the section "Weak convergence".

> For each $K<\infty$ and $y<1$ there is a $c_{y,K}>0$ so that $EX^2=1$ and $EX^4\leqslant K$ implies $P(|X|>y)\geqslant c_{y,K}$.

I've tried Chebyshev inequality but it gives a upper bound instead a lower bound of $P(|X|>y)$. And now I don't know how to continue it. I would be grateful if someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! On this website, it is customary to write out your attempt before receiving an answer to incentivize people trying. What have you tried? (If you have no idea how to start, try thinking of Chebyshev's inequality and perhaps update the question with attempts to apply to Chebyshev to various random variables related to |X|.)

Comment: Thanks for advice.

Comment: OK, try using Paley-Zygmund now: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to E-A's comments above. This is a simple application of Paley-Zygmund inequality. To prove it directly, we consider \begin{align*}
1=E(X^2)&=E(X^21_{X^2\leqslant y^2})+E(X^21_{X^2>y^2})\\
&\leqslant y^2+E^{\frac12}(X^4)P^{\frac12}(X^2>y^2)\\
&\leqslant y^2+\sqrt{K}P^{\frac12}(X^2>y^2)
\end{align*}
It follows that $$P(|X|>y)=P(X^2>y^2)\geqslant \frac{(1-y^2)^2}K$$